# deactivate WPBakery Page Builder license

Tags: plugins

I need to deactivate the license and reinstall it ... will it be such that my content that I wrote and those blocks that I set to be deleted and not appear again with the new license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The change of license should not have a direct impact on the created content. The created blocks/content will still be stored on the database and will be accessible after enabling the new license.

However, you should ALWAYS do a previous backup, just in case.

It's better to be safe than sorry ;-)

Comment: I'm just really afraid that everything will leave. It’s just that the new client has nothing to lose, but a different license is needed ...

Comment: Since the blocks are stored on the database and you will just change the key. the content is not erased.